# Under what conditions is a norm on an algebra equivalent to a submultiplicative norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras, algebras

I've heard that the reason normed algebras are defined as having a **submultiplicative** norm is because there is no loss of generality, since every norm on an algebra is equivalent to a submultiplicative norm.

I can't quite figure out why this would be the case, or whether it only applies to specific types of algebras.

Not having much luck searching on the net. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: For the case of Banach algebras this holds. You just need to notice that the Banach algebra $X$ is isomorphic to a closed subalgebra of $B(X)$ (the space of bounded operators from $X$ to itself) via the mapping $A \mapsto L_A$, where $L_A$ is the operator that maps $B \in X$ to $AB \in X$. Hence, the norm on $X$ is equivalent to the restriction of the norm on $B(X)$, which is obviously submultiplicative. But i think you need the uniform boundedness principle, so the completeness can't be dropped.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets: this is the obvious thing to try but why is it clear that $L_A$ is bounded if you don't assume submultiplicativity?

Comment: As Qiaochu Yuan says, I have seen the above argument before but what was not explained was how exactly can you guarantee that $L_a$ is bounded for each $a$ unless you use submultiplicativity.

Comment: In normed algebras you usually require multiplication to be separately continuous. Which is precisely the continuity of those $L_A$'s (and $R_A$'s).
For a norm in which multiplication is not separately continuous this obviously does not hold as having equivalent submultiplicative norm implies the separate continuity of multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**.  Let $X$ be a Banach space equipped with a separately continuous  bilinear map
$$
  \mu :X\times X\to X.
  $$
Then there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$
  \|\mu (x,y)\|\leq C\|x\|\|y\|, \quad \forall x,y\in X.
  $$

*Proof*. For each $a$ in $X$,  let
$$
  L_a : x\in  X\mapsto  \mu (a,x)\in  X,
$$ and $$
  R_a : x\in  X\mapsto  \mu (x, a)\in  X.
  $$
Each $L_a$ and each $R_a$ is bounded by assumption and we claim that
$$
  \sup_{\|a\|\leq 1}\|L_a\|<\infty .
  $$
By the uniform boundedness principle it
is enough to show that, for every fixed $x$ in $X$, one has that
$$
  \sup_{\|a\|\leq 1}\|L_a(x)\|<\infty ,
  \tag{1}
  $$
but this follows easily from
$$
  \|L_a(x)\| =   \|ax\| =   \|R_x(a)\| \leq  $$$$ \leq\|R_x\|\|a\| \leq  \|R_x\|.
  $$
Letting $C$ be the supremum in (1), we get
$$
  \|\mu(x,y)\| =
  \|x\|\left\|\mu\left({x\over \|x\|},y\right)\right\| = $$$$ =
 \|x\|\|L_{{x\over \|x\|}}(y)\|   \leq C\|x\|\|y\|.
  $$
QED

**Corollary**. If $A$ is a Banach space as well as an algebra, such that the multiplication operation  is separately continuous, then
there exists a constant $C$, such that the norm $|||\cdot|||$ defined  on $A$ by
$$
  |||a||| := C\|a\|,
  $$
is submultiplicative.

*Proof*.   By the Lemma there  is a constant $C$ such that
$$
  \|xy\|\leq C\|x\|\|y\|, \quad \forall x,y\in X,
  $$
so
$$
  C\|xy\|\leq (C\|x\|)(C\|y\|).
  $$
QED