# Banach space with continuous multiplication is a Banach algebra

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Consider a Banach space $(\mathcal{A},\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}}$) and assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is also an associative algebra with a unit element $I\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\|I\|_{\mathcal{A}}=1$. Furthermore, suppose that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$
$$\|AB\|_{\mathcal{A}}\leq C\|A\|_{\mathcal{A}}\|B\|_{\mathcal{A}}. $$

It's obvious [(see e.g. this post)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881006/under-what-conditions-is-a-norm-on-an-algebra-equivalent-to-a-submultiplicative) that one can rescale the norm to obtain an equivalent norm that is submultiplicative. However, in this case the identity element will no longer have norm one.

**Question:** How can we define an equivalent norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{A}}'$ on $\mathcal{A}$ such that this new norm is submultiplicative and $\|I\|_{\mathcal{A}}'=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$\|A\|'=\sup\{\|AB\| : \|B\|\leq 1\}.$$

Comment: I agree that this is an equivalent norm and that the unit element has norm one, but could you add a few more details why this is submultiplicative?

Comment: The new norm of $A$ is precisely the operator norm of the *left multiplication operator* $$
L_A:B\mapsto AB.
$$
Therefore $$\|AB\|' =\|L_{AB}\|=\|L_A\circ L_{B}\|\leq
\|L_A\|\| L_{B}\|=
\|A\|'\|B\|'
$$